# android - styling submenu triangle icon

Tags: android

I can't seem to find the correct area to style the little triangle icon on my submenu.  I want it to be white in color but everything I try seems to make it colored black.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like this style node of the main theme affects the color of the submenu arrow/triangle:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
```

so changing this to color/white has changed the arrow to white - but any other default text must be manually set to black now.

EDIT: I solved this a better way that doesn't effect the rest of the text color in the activity styled.

in my main theme, i defined actionBarStyle:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MainActActionBar</item>
```

then I define:

```
<style name="MainActActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse" >
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/MainActionBarMenu</item>
</style>
```

and lastly:

```
<style name="MainActionBarMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow" >       
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

this gives me the white arrow i was looking for and doesn't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

copy this line in your style that you have choosen.

`<item name="subMenuArrow">@style/MyStyle</item>`

and define Mystyle like this in your style.xml file

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListMenuView">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```